# Google App Engine: image to base64 String for OCR (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, base64, blob, ocr

I have the following code in Google App Engine, which accepts an image from the user, and subsequently performs an OCR on that image.

index.html:

```
<form action="/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="newImage" capture="camera">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

main.py:

```
import requests

def image_to_text(encoded_string, content_type="jpeg"):

    api_key = "API_KEY"
    overlay = False  
    language = 'eng'

    payload = {'isOverlayRequired': overlay,
           'apikey': api_key,
           'language': language,
           'base64Image': "data:image/{};base64,{}".format(content_type,
                                                           encoded_string)
           }

    r = requests.post('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image',
                  data=payload)
    return r.content.decode() 



class Submit(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        new_image = self.request.get("newImage")
        if new_image is not '': # ie user uploads an image
            IMG = UploadImage()
            IMG.img = new_image # ndb.BlobProperty()
            img_key = IMG.put() # stores it in datastore
            img_key_url = img_key.urlsafe()
            base64_string = new_image.encode('base64') # this is the step that I may be doing wrongly
            text= image_to_text(base64_string)
```

However, I got an error stating that it isn't a valid base64 image.

The following code (for reading an image and converting it to base64 string) works when I read a file from my local disk though. (The OCR API that I'm using can be found here: https://ocr.space/ocrapi#python

OCR.py:

```
import requests
import base64

def image_to_text(base64_encoded_string=None,content_type="jpeg"):
    filename = 'image.jpg'
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(f.read()).strip('\n')

        api_key = "API_KEY"
        overlay = False # Boolean value indicating if the overlay is required along with the image/pdf parsed result
        language = 'eng'

        payload = {'isOverlayRequired': overlay,
            'apikey': api_key,
            'language': language,
           'base64Image':"data:image/{};base64,{}".format(content_type,
                                                            encoded_string)
            }



    r = requests.post('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image',
                        data=payload)
    return r.content.decode()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait I solved it on my own by doing this:

```
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image).strip('\n')
```